# How to convert year and week of year obtained from MongoDB query into Joda datetime?

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime

I'm using $year and $week in MongoDB aggregation query to group results by year and week of year. In the Java code I want to convert the returned year, week of year to a DateTime object, to allow easier presentation of the data.

It seems that Joda DateTime's getWeekOfWeekyear() doesn't behave the same way as $week in MongoDB, and this causes different date results.

1. **Scenario 1**

MongoDB query:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$project:
   {week: {$week: ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") },
    year: {$year: ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") } }
  }
)
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : "", "week" : 0, "year" : 2016 }
```

When trying to convert those values to Joda DateTime object, it throws an exception: IllegalFieldValueException.

```
(new DateTime(0, DateTimeZone.UTC)).withWeekyear(2016).withWeekOfWeekyear(0).withDayOfWeek(1).toString()
```

2. **Scenario 2**

In addition, when querying for 2015-05-10, which is Sunday.

MongoDB query:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$project:
   {week: {$week: ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") },
    year: {$year: ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") } }
  }
)
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : "", "week" : 19, "year" : 2015 }
```

But when trying to convert to Joda DateTime, this results in the previous week, starts at 2015-05-04:

```
(new DateTime(0, DateTimeZone.UTC)).withWeekyear(2015).withWeekOfWeekyear(19).withDayOfWeek(1).toString()
```

results in:

```
2015-05-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

Mongo $week operator returns the week of the year as a number between 0 and 53. Weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the year. Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0. In Java, WeekOfYear returned value, the first week of the year is that in which at least 4 days are in the year. As a result of this definition, day 1 of the first week may be in the previous year. Also week starts on Monday.

Is there a way to solve this inconsistency in the Java code?

Comment: Week starts on Sunday and Monday is the first work day of the week. Both Mongo and Joda DateTime has it correct. Also first week of the year may have first day in last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ISO 8601

Joda-Time follows the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard in [defining weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

- Monday is the first day of the week.
- Weeks are numbered 1 to 52 or 53.
- Week numbers are written with an uppercase `W`, such as `W23`.
  Year may be prepended, `2015-W23`.
- Week # 1, `W01`, contains the year's first Thursday.

As far as I know, this standard definition has been growing more common in usage in various countries and industries.

## Sunday Weeks

The [MongoDB doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/) defines weeks as:

> …the week of the year for a date as a number between 0 and 53.
>
> Weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the year. Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0. This behavior is the same as the “%U” operator to the strftime standard library function.

As far as I know, this is a mostly American definition, not used much outside the US.

Why does that definition say 0 to 53? That means "up to 54 weeks". I don't think this definition would produce 54 weeks in any year, but I've not thought it through.

## Why Mix?

You cannot really mix the two definitions. Why bother? If your goal is to use MongoDB’s definition of weeks, and represent them by a date-time, then write your own converter.

My own advice would be to ditch MongoDB’s definition and function, and stick with the standard definition.

## Find Sunday

If you want to find the Sunday starting a week in MongoDB’s world, write your own little function. Feed in the year number and week number, and get back a DateTime. In this scenario, you have no need for Joda-Time’s week-of-year features.

Something like this.

```
int yearNumber = 2015;
int weekNumber = 0;

LocalDate firstWeekSunday = null;
LocalDate firstOfYear = new LocalDate ( yearNumber, 1, 1 );
if ( firstOfYear.getDayOfWeek ( ) == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY ) {
    firstWeekSunday = firstOfYear;
} else { // ELSE not Sunday.
    firstWeekSunday = firstOfYear.minusDays ( firstOfYear.getDayOfWeek ( ) );  // Joda-Time uses standard ISO 8601 weeks, where Monday = 1, Sunday = 7.
}
LocalDate sunday = firstWeekSunday.plusWeeks ( weekNumber );

DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID ( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTime = sunday.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay ( zone );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "Sunday-based week of year:" + yearNumber + " week: " + weekNumber + " starts: " + sunday + "." );
System.out.println ( "Adjusted to time zone: " + zone + " is: " + dateTime + "." );
```

When run.

```
Sunday-based week of year:2015 week: 0 starts: 2014-12-28.
Adjusted to time zone: America/Montreal is: 2014-12-28T00:00:00.000-05:00.
```